# Wrong Swift Code in a Transfer from Korea to Spain

Tags: transfer

A client from Korea with Woori Bank made a transfer 1 week ago of 20,000 EUR, I was surprised that it did not come yet to me (an international transfer does not usually take more than 5 days excluding weekends) I told him to give me the details of the transfer, the account number is fine, name of the bank, country and both the name and address too but then I noticed that in the swift code he had a little mistake, the swift code of CaixaBank is CAIXESBBXXX and he put CAIXAESBBXXX.

I told him to go to his bank to find out where the money is and fill a request to get it back but the bank refused to give him information because the money has already reached its destination... the issue is that nothing has come to me.

I dont think the money ended in hands of other because it would be so much coincidental that someone else had the same information as me in my country.

What should I do? Should I go to my bank to see if they have it?

Comment: Banks don't usually look at people's names. The money likely went into the account with the same number as yours at a different bank (that's assuming that the swift code is actually valid for a different bank).

Comment: There is no banks here with CAIXAESBB of swift code, in fact no bank has 9 letters in the swift, only 8.

Comment: In that case you might have to wait a while until the money is returned to your client so he can re-send it. maybe a couple weeks.

Comment: In situations like this, the case of Susan Madakor, https://oios.un.org/resources/reports/a55_353.htm is instructive...